# Discriminate Maths Equation Understanding

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$X = \{x : 3x²−x−2=0\}$ the result is $x=1$ or $x=-\frac{2}{3}$ I must not be reading the question correctly as if $x=1$ wouldn't the question be $X = \{x : 31^2−1−2=0\}$ ?  Sorry I am rather new to this ^.^

Also do you guys rap equations in the CODE tags here?

What tags would this type of question best go under?

Thanks.

Comment: Is X a set, i.e., $\{\cdot\}$, or is it something else? Also, $3x^2=3\cdot x^2$. So at $x=1$, $3x^2=3\cdot1^2=3\neq 31^2$.

Comment: Yes X is a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$X = \{x|3x²−x−2=0\}$$
Solving the equation
$$3x²−x−2=0$$
gives
$$x=\frac{-(-1)\pm\sqrt{(-1)^2-4\cdot3\cdot(-2)}}{6}=1,-\frac{2}{3}$$
Thus, $$X=\{1,-\frac{2}{3}\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$X=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: 3x^2-x-2=0\}=\{-\frac{2}{3},1\}$$